# Web Application similar Native Client

Tags: web-applications, offline-mode

I am wanting to port my application to a web app.

The app should:

1. Be able to access the local hard drive
2. The data should be stored locally (in case of denial of service attacks to my web server).
3. Take advantage of the local CPU.
4. Run in any browser, in any OS
5. No plugins required.

Basically, I want an web app that will run in any browser and in any operating system. Requires no plugins to use. And not susceptible to denial of service attacks.

I have heard of Native Client from Google, but this is in its embryonic stage and it may only run with Chromium and or Chrome (not in IE, Firefox, Safari etc).

I don't want to use flash because it requires a plugin which can be blocked by users computers (security policy of company laptops). Also, I heard flash is dying.

Also, I've heard Jave/JSP/Applets are dead.

What development environment will allow me to achieve the above? Does .NET? Silverlight?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to access the users local hard drive directly without a plug-in would be a violation of security and just can't be done. Unless you are referring to users being able to upload files to the server to store! which can be done; but its all within the users control.

If the data you wish to save on the user-end is small the only option you would have is cookies without any plug-in at all and the amount of data you can store is very small indeed.

HTML5 introduces application storage but its support is very very low so i doubt this would suit you either as users can define how much room each application can use and it defaults to a smallish amount.

You can use as much CPU as you like i guess... however you must realise that a lot of people run multiple applications, services and websites at once and they all share CPU usage! so don't expect old mum's laptop to perform and keep up if you plan to use a lot of CPU intensive operations on the client end.... Server side CPU; it will be up to your hosting provider as to how much you can use, some cloud hosting providers make you pay CPU usage even.

If your site is under attack it wouldn't matter if it was flash, silverlight, a normal web page, a native client application or how much data you stored on the user-end... if a browser can't request the page, the page will not load and nothing will appear except a local error page, so none of these technologies will make you 'safe' from a DOS attack or any other kind of attack and users will find they simply can't load the site or page anyway.

Silverlight is similar to Flash, Java applets and the google 'native client' and everything else! in that its a plug-in users have to install and can optionally disable, so i gather none of these options are for you... without relying on a plug-in your options are only basic javascript and HTML and nothing else, and a lot of companies disable *all* plug-ins or allow only a very selected few e.g adobe reader only... some even disable javascript so can't do any kind of coding at all on the client :)

It all depends on what EXACTLY you need to do, why do you need access to a users hard drive... why do you specify you need take advantage of the CPU? and why is there a no-plug's rule yet you talk about using plug-ins anyway?

Comment: OK - well I don't really need to access the users hard drive. I just need a way to ensure that only that computer runs the application in case they decide to "share" the application. The CPU bit - it just means I need to run it locally. I wouldn't be controlling the CPU processes. The program uses some crunching and I don't think 3000 users accessing number crunching modules on the server simultaneously is a a good idea. No Plug-ins? I have sold my app to schools and they have high restrictions on what they can and cannot install. This has reduced who I can sell to.

Comment: And one final thing, the app is written in VB6. This cuts out all the Mac users - and with the coming of Windows 8, I need to think of something quick.

Comment: You can do really good number crunching with javascript and almost everyone has a browser that will at least run that, all depends on what you want to specifically :)

Comment: HTML+Javascript client-side and .NET/Java/PHP/Python/Ruby/etc server-side will accomplish almost anything you should need. A cloud-based server-side setup will take care of any level of number crunching server-side that you might need as you can automatically grow your virtual web farm as your needs grow (eg tasks that can't be left to user-end like authorization and even image resizing, database lookups etc) the rest can be client-side. Again just depends on what features you need really... anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: For sharing you can get the clients IP address, in the case of NAT gateways and proxies you will get the NAT/proxy IP of course but schools/university's will at least be identifiable that way if you so choose? A hardcore option of course! the other option is authentication and its more flexible as users can then login via mobile phones with web browsers, from home etc but it will all be logged against them as a user (providing you log the access heh)

Comment: Javascript is an option - but is there a way to hide the code? What stops people from just viewing the page source to access my code/data?

Comment: 3k users isn't really a lot at all for a normal site with DB look ups and the like, one site i've launched have had 50,000 users sign up on the first day :) ( thanks to TV and newspaper advertising all over Australia ) and almost all the code is server-side with very basic HTML/JS client-side. Pick a good hosting provider of course, cloud hosts are great eg GoGrid, Rackspace Cloud, Amazon and even the MS Cloud

Comment: I've thought of using the IP to identify the computer - but don't IP's change - eg if you do a "repair" on your network icon in the tray - does that renew and give you a new IP. Also, what about computers behind a large school/corporate network, are the IPs static and accessible?

Comment: can't stop anyone from viewing your java script, you can obfuscate it... but people will be able to decode it. I gather it's the kind of code they shouldn't be looking at then? :) in that case if its just database queries (INSERTS, SELECTS, UPDATES, DELETES) formatting and basic outputting you should be fine to do this server-side even for lots of users. If its just formatting of basic data you can leave that client-side

Comment: Local IP's are very different to WAN IP's, and you can only read the public/WAN IP at the web server end, when you renew locally normally you just get a new IP from your router or other controller and your public WAN stays the same. HOWEVER! its certainly true that some ISP's rotate IP address's so i would go for normal authentication methods if possible or IP ranges and authentication, otherwise they would need to get a static or work on a more elaborate method heh

Comment: Yeah - I am thinking of intellectual property and don't want my competitors from "borrowing" my code or methods. Javascript for front end sounds like a good idea. If 3000 users isn't really all that large and larger hosting companies can support it, then I guess I could move the brains back to the server side. Sounds like you have had some experience in it White Dragon! - Thanks

Comment: Authentication - what stops a user from giving their login and password to a couple of their (non paying) friends? My current vb6 app reads HDD information to identify the computer and refuses to run unless that computer has "paid". Can Javascript access this type of info? I thought it couldn't.

Comment: You can provide cookie information that will be kept with the specific browser until it times out or is cleared but that's not likely what you are after i think. HTTP and HTML are designed to be a stateless and open protocols (no direct OS/API ties). A basic way to protect from theft would be to log every login attempt time and IP address, you can then see if users from other states, countries and ISP's are using the account and you'll know then its being "borrowed".

Comment: You can also provide password refreshes to clients directly, this way 'shared' access will get cut off back to the paid client every 1-2 months to help curb the effect. Lastly you can tell them they *must* use a HTML5 compatible browser to use the website and use the HTML5 application store as i don't think this will be cleared normally... however users can forcefully clear it, if they do they can likly contact you for a new key?

Comment: of course forcing them to use a browser type or version doesn't always work either :) but if they were happy to install a VB6 application they should be happy to update their browser at least you would think? even if its locked down with no plug-in support

Comment: as to java script accessing computer level data, while you can access it via ActiveX objects and the like; even do file operations etc 'technically', in *reality* these options are almost always completely locked down even in normal users browsers so its really a no for all intents and purposes

Comment: Thanks. I guess there is no such thing a software that cannot be pirated. But I have a direction - that is go server side since client side (active x and plugins) are often blocked. Server-side code generates the front end in HTML and thus is totally portable. I will have to sacrifice some client control but I think it may be worth it. Cheers

Comment: Good luck! and remember there is always a lot you can do with AJAX and jQuery/jQueryUI to make a great user interface, you can even have pages that are 'flash-like' just using javascript and AJAX is very handy for loading data from the server without refreshing/rendering an entire new page great for active feeds and fast server queries rendered using JS

Answer (score 1):

It sure is bad news to hear that so many things are suddenly dead or dying...

Anyway, if your requirement is "any browser on any OS" then you're talking about HTML, plain and simple.  Drop some browsers from that requirement and you can include JavaScript.

Local CPU as opposed to what?  Using server resources?  Not with HTML/JavaScript.  Local data storage will be odd, HTML5 isn't supported by everything yet but it might be something to look at for that.

And what's with the DoS attack vector?  Why is that such a relevant concern?

You may have mutually exclusive requirements here, and potentially not a full grasp of web development as a platform or architecture.  More to the point, this is a *really* vague question with almost no information and, from the perspective of others, nonsensical requirements.  Please elaborate.

Comment: As for DoS - If I have 3000 students accessing my web apps in a very crucial time of the year (near exams), and my site gets a DoS attack (initiated by my competitors), then I will have to face the music. I would rather just leave my app as a legacy VB6 app, but with Windows 8 and no guarantees of support for legacy apps, then I have about a year to do something.